# Is there any way I can avoid specifying the port in the alluxio fs uri?

Tags: alluxio

If i have a domain  name for my alluxio master, is there any way I can avoid specifying the port in the alluxio fs uri. Like instead of `alluxio://<master ip>:<port>/<filepath>` just `alluxio://<alluxio master domain name>/<filepath>`

Also if i have a domain name for alluxio master can i add a path to it like `alluxio://<alluxio master domain name>/<subpath>/<filepath>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that `alluxio://<alluxio master domain name>/` works. The default master web port is 19999, if you want to specify another master web port, you can either put it in `alluxio://<master ip>:<port>/` or configure `alluxio.master.web.port=<value>`